# How do i get this use effect/Functon to only run If -hours variable has changed

Tags: reactjs, debugging, react-context

I'm working on a personal/ Business project. I'm attempting to give clients a quote on my website. There is an option to add packages and addons. Once the finalquote component loads it calculates the total based on the amount of hours stores in my context file as this.state.hours.

The problem I'm having is it runs the calculation even if hours have changed. For instance when I click admin dashboard addon and go to the next page it add the amount when I remount the component it adds the same amount even though I have not changed or added any hours to the variable.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext, useRef } from 'react';
import { ProductContext } from '../pages/oniContext';
import { Container, Badge } from 'reactstrap';
import {
  Subtitle,
  Description,
  Titlespan2,
} from '../components/common/title/index';
import { total } from '../components/total';
export const FinalQuote = () => {
  const { hours, setTotal,total,activeAddOns, } = useContext(ProductContext);
  const prevCountRef = useRef();
  

  useEffect(() => {
    alert('Run');
    console.log(hours, 'Final Quote Run', total);
    setTotal();
    console.error(hours);
  }, [hours]);

  return (
    <section className="testimonial-wrapper gradient-color" id="testimonial">
      <Container>
        <div className="main-title-wrapper">
          <Subtitle Class="site-subtitle gradient-color" Name="Your Quote" />
          <Titlespan2
            Class="sitemain-subtitle"
            Name={`$${Math.round(total)}`}
          />
          <Description
            Class="site-dec"
            Name="The Shown Price is only an estimate and may increase or decrease based on demand and extent of work"
          />
          {activeAddOns.map((service, index) => (
            <Badge color="info" pill>
              {service.title}
            </Badge>
          ))}
        </div>
      </Container>
    </section>
  );
};
```

Context Set total function

```
setTotal = () => {
    if (this.state.hours > 0) {
       this.setState((prevState) => {
         if (prevState.hours === this.state.hours) {
           console.log(prevState.hours);
         }
         return {
           total: this.state.total + this.state.hours * ratePerHour * Math.PI,
         };
       });
      console.log(this.state.total, '+', this.state.hours, '*', ratePerHour);
    }
    
  };
```

Comment: The effect will always run on mount. If you don't want that behaviour then don't unmount it in the first place, or move the calculation higher up in the tree

Comment: How do i stop it from unmounting?

Comment: and if youre going to downvote how do i run a function only if a variable has changed?

Comment: Check the parent to component to see why it's unmounting, then don't do that

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but the way you have written the effect is correct, it will run a) when it mounts and b) when `hours` has changed. It's hard to tell from your code why that effect is in this component in the first place. why don't you set the total in the context provider?

Comment: Im trying to show the total when the componenet is mounted.Should i put it in a button or set it in context after i add more hours?

Comment: It's up to you how you want to do it. I think setting the total everytime you change the hours makes sense to me, no need to call a separate function